# What is the reason you can only take flucloxacillin on an empty stomach?

Tags: medications

Is there a specific type of food that causes flucloxacillin to not be abosrbed more so than other kinds of food?

Specifically could somebody eat for example a handful of almonds or peanuts as a small snack without it causing the flucloxacillin to lose effectiveness?